# My discord bot is not looping through the entire entire array it needs to

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, discord.py

I currently have a script which loops through a list of JSON results and extracts certain information for each result. I currently am trying to extract the tags for each result which located inside the animalURLS list.

The loop is successfully able to go through the list if i don't add the `if statement`. However, the output changes if I were to add the `if statement`, it only goes through part of the entire list of results that I have. The maximum number of items it will print is 85 with the `if statement`. There would be certain results that would be missed even if it has the appropriate tag.

Here is a list of possible tags:

- cat
- dog
- bird
- other

I am not sure why my code isn't working for certain results and would appreciate any help.

```py
            for i, v in enumerate(miskaJSON[str(ctx.guild.id)]["animalURLS"]):
                if v[2] == tag:
                    print(v)
                    print(i)
```

This is an example of a miskaJSONStructure, which is what my code is based upon. The tag is the last item on the animalURLS list:

```
    "628704494615789599": {
        "prefix": "%",
        "animalURLS": [
            [
                "Darth Kylo-Kun",
                "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/628704495047671818/723325532397109329/IMG_20170531_140251.png",
                "cat"
            ]
        ],
        "tags": [
            "cat",
            "dog",
            "bird",
            "other"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: can you put miskaJSON structure please

Comment: sure give me a sec

Comment: Added json structure

Comment: any errors displayed in the console ?

Answer (score 1):

> **Please note that this answer is based on my assumption. I wouldn't be able to confirm without seeing the actual data.**

Based on what I am seeing, the animalURLS list has three things:

- Comment by the poster
- Image URL
- Tag

The reason why your answer works, is that there could be a few additional items in animalURLS which contains some other information. This means that there would be more than three items in the list and `v[2]` might not always be a tag.

```
for i, v in enumerate(miskaJSON[str(ctx.guild.id)]["animalURLS"]):
    # v[-1] would get the last item on the list which you are assuming would be a tag.
    if v[-1] == tag:
        validIndices.append(i)
```

To see what is `v[2]` if it is not a tag, you can try the following:

```
valid_tags = []
invalid_tags = []

for i, v in enumerate(miskaJSON[str(ctx.guild.id)]["animalURLS"]):
    if v[2] == tag:
        valid_tags.append(v[2])
    else:
        invalid_tags.append(v[2])

print(f"Total Valid Tags: {len(valid_tags)} | Valid Tags: {valid_tags}")
print(f"Total Invalid Tags: {len(invalid_tags)} | Invalid Tags: {invalid_tags}")
```

The way I would do it is, assuming the last item in animalURLS is always a tag, you could use the following to check if the tag matches your list of tags if that is your goal.

```
for i, v in enumerate(miskaJSON[str(ctx.guild.id)]["animalURLS"]):
    if v[-1] in miskaJSON[str(ctx.guild.id)]["tags"]:
        print(v)
        print(i)
```

Expected Input JSON:

```
    "628704494615789599": {
        "prefix": "%",
        "animalURLS": [
            [
                "Darth Kylo-Kun", # Comment
                "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/628704495047671818/723325532397109329/IMG_20170531_140251.png", # URL
                "cat" # Tag
            ]
        ],
        "tags": [
            "cat",
            "dog",
            "bird",
            "other"
        ]
    }
```

Possible Unexpected Input JSON:

```
    "628704494615789599": {
        "prefix": "%",
        "animalURLS": [
            [
                "Darth Kylo-Kun", # Comment
                "random stuff in between",
                "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/628704495047671818/723325532397109329/IMG_20170531_140251.png", # URL
                "random stuff in between",
                "cat" # Tag
            ]
        ],
        "tags": [
            "cat",
            "dog",
            "bird",
            "other"
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i, v in enumerate(miskaJSON[str(ctx.guild.id)]["animalURLS"]):
    if v[-1] == tag:
        validIndices.append(i)
```

Somehow this fixed and i have no idea why

Comment: may be "animalURLS" have more than 3 values. that's why it worked